# After close the plot window the process keeps running

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

Im new in matplotlib and having some hard times. From the user point of view everything works fine.
I have a window with a button. Pressing the button a new window pops showing the plot. After play
with it i click at X to close this window. And click at X again to close the window with the button.
BUT im not dropped back to a free prompt. The main window is locked and still running in background.

Here goes the important parts of code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as Plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent): #=None

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

                       .... wxpython stuff goes here....

              self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cplot)

                       ....

    def cplot(self, event):
        self.new = NewWindow(self)
        self.new.cidadeplot(self)
        self.new.Show()
        return


class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,event):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Plot', size=(556, 618))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)


    def OnClose(self,event):
        self.Destroy()


    def cidplot(self,event):


        self.fig = Figure()

        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

        self.axes.set_ylabel("Parts")
        self.axes.set_ylim(0,100)
        self.axes.grid(True)

        ....more axes settings...

       bars = self.axes.bar(left=self.ii, height=self.tt, width=0.2, align='center', alpha=0.8)

        ....

        self.canvas.draw()

        Plt.savefig("Parts.pdf", dpi=300)



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title = "System Test")

        self.SetSize((556, 618))

        panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I think the problem is at self.fig = Figure() (Same happens if i use Plt.figure())

Im doing something wrong when i create a new window or is at my matplotlib part?
Some better way to do it?

Thanks in advance. Any ideia is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do not import `pyplot`, it has it's own wrapping to deal with managing figure gui frames which (in addition to the state machine interface) is the main point of `pyplot`.  To do this it starts it's own mainloop, which is probably what is messing you up.

Make sure you look at the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function OnClose:

```
def onClose(self, event):
    """"""
    self.Close(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcaswell was right.

I removed all reference to pyplot. The savefig was locking the app.
Changed all to self.axes.XXX and salf.fig.savefig(xxx) and worked.

Thanks.